# Which is faster: repeating styles or repeating selectors?

Tags: css

I would like to know which of the following examples will perform better.  If performance is the same, which one reads better?

**Example 1 (Repeating Selectors)**

`.helpfulCommenter, .questionTroll {
    color: #f00;
}`

.questionTroll {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

or

**Example 2 (Repeating styles)**

`.helpfulCommenter { color: #f00; }`

.questionTroll { color: #f00; text-decoration: line-through; }

I know the class names are not semantic and the particular styles demonstrated here are irrelevant.  I just want to know which of these do browsers have an easier time parsing and implementing.

Comment: The performance of this likely varies between browsers and is vastly dependent on the number of elements and selectors you have. Ultimately, though, the performance difference here is non-important—choose whichever one makes more semantic sense.

Comment: The class names violate good practices (you are hard-coding the values ("red", "bold") into the class names). You should have come up with better (proper) names...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm sure these were just examples he came up with.

Comment: "I know the class names are not semantic and the particular styles demonstrated here are irrelevant." Then provide semantic, real-world examples that are worth comparing for readability. There are very few properties to worry about performance-wise (transforms and transitions, maybe), unless you're developing a layout engine, which clearly you're not.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I know they are not semantic names.  As noted in the original question, these class names are for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: @xbonez Yes, the OP implies that himself. However, I fail to see the reasoning behind providing badly written example code.

Comment: Opera is the only browser that has a metric to time style rendering, so I guess it's the only place to find out.

Comment: @Jason [I'll just leave this here](http://memegenerator.net/instance/15827397) `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference is so minuscule it's irrelevant.

Shy away from example 2 as it will, most likely, become a maintenance headache if abused.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, that the differences between the two were more related to code maintenance than performance.  Does the same apply if I have many classes (> 50 or even into the hundreds) that need to share styles?

Comment: @Jason how would it be different than having the same definition on different selectors. If you design your `CSS` properly you should have cascading styles that minimize repetition and a shortened StyleSheet.

Comment: @Xander That's ultimately what I'm asking.  Thanks for the help.